# Many to many relationship with hierarchy in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I am new to SSAS and have a situation where I need help.

I have a many to many relationship table which contains info about the competitors of a property and the type of competitor it is at any given date.

So, something like this:

`PID       Type       CompID       Date
1          A          1           1/1/2001
1          A          2           1/1/2001
1          B          1           2/1/2001
1          B          1           3/1/2001
2          A          1           1/1/2001
2          B          1           1/1/2001`

Now I need to include this in the cube and relate it to the main fact table. I have defined the relationship as a many to many but while writing the query to retrieve the information using MDX, I am stuck.

What I need is all the measures for a given property and all the aggregated measures of all its competitors of a given type at a given date.

So, given a proeprty ID, I need to identify the list of its competitors of a given type and on a given date and then I have to aggregate the measures for all these competitor properties.

I am stuck at this place where I have to identify all the competitors of a given property.

e.g. if I fire this query:

```
Select 
{
  TYNBC,YOYNBC_Improvement,LYNBC,TYADR,YOYADR_Improvement,LYADR
}
on 1,
Stay_DATE.Month.Month on 0
FROM Cube1
where {Hotel.Hotel_Key.&[480]}*{Stay_DATE.Hierarchy.Year.&[2015]}
```

The result would be the measures for a given property. 
What I want in the result is all the above measures and the same measures for the competitors of the property 480 for a given date and a given competitor type. The issue I am facing is in identifying the competitors of the property in mdx because competitor table is added as a factless fact with many to many relationship in the cube. So, how do I retrieve the list of competitor properties when there is no hierarchy defined as it is not a dimension.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What are the dimensions and measure groups in your cube? What MDX have you tried till now?

Comment: Edited my initial post with more info.

Comment: Does this help retrieve the competitors for a property: `WITH SET Competitors AS NonEmpty(Competitor.Competitors.MEMBERS, (EXISTING Hotel.Hotel_Key.MEMBERS, TYNBC))`

Comment: If it works, I will prepare a solution for you.